# How to efficiently retrieve all record in rails 3.2 and assign them to a query-able object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In our rails 3.2 app, we need to retrieve all customer records out of customer table and assign them to a variable `customers` and do query (such as .where(:active => true) on variable `customers` late on. There are 2 questions here:

1. what's the better way to retrieve all records?

   `Customer.all` works. However according to rails document, it may have performance issue when Customer table gets large. We tried `Customer.find_each` and it has error `"no block given (yield)"`.
2. How to make the variable `customers` query_able?

   When performing query on variable `customers` (like `customers.where(:active => true)`), there is an error: `undefined method`where' for #`. It seems that the`customers`is an array object and can't take`where`. How can we retrieve`customers` in such a way it can be query-able?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails < 4 `.all` makes database call immediately, loads records and returns array. Instead use "lazy" [scoped](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scoped) method which returns chainable `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. E.g.:

```
customers = Customer.scoped
...
customers = customers.where(:active => true)
customers = customers.where(...)
etc...
```

And at the moment when you will need to load records and iterate over them you can call [find_each](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each):

```
customers.find_each do |customer|
  ...
end
```

Comment: scoped works in our rails 3.2.12. Thanks. BTW is it deprecated in rails 4?

Comment: Yes it is deprecated. In Rails 4 'all' method is equivalent to 'scoped'